# Spring-Integration: multithreaded creation of sftp directories with common root fails

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have multiple threads which upload sftp files through an `Sftp.outboundAdapter`. Each thread needs to create a directory path with a common root. I get an exception which tells me that the common root exists:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to transfer file
...
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to create remote directory '/my/import/de3fb731-6a56-11e9-bfd2-0242ac140022'.; nested exception is 4: Eine Datei kann nicht erstellt werden, wenn sie bereits vorhanden ist. 
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.mkdir(SftpSession.java:232)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileUtils.makeDirectories(RemoteFileUtils.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:545)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:337)
    ... 150 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: Eine Datei kann nicht erstellt werden, wenn sie bereits vorhanden ist. 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.mkdir(ChannelSftp.java:2182)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.mkdir(SftpSession.java:229)
    ... 153 common frames omitted
```

I guess there is a race condition in `RemoteFileUtils#makeDirectories` when it determines the `pathsToCreate`. Both threads determine that the path segment needs to be created, but when both try to create it, the second one fails.

A possible workaround is to create the common path in advance, but that is clumsy because there is no such command in the `Sftp.outboundGateway`, It seems I  have to upload a dummy file with `autoCreateDirectories` and delete the dummy file afterwards.

Is there a better way to solve this? Would it make sense to add an mkdirs command to the sftp outbound gateway? Should there be a flag to ignore errors due to existing directories when `autoCreateDirectories` is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A possible workaround is to create the common path in advance, but that is clumsy because there is no such command in the Sftp.outboundGateway

You could simply call `RemoteFileUtils.makeDirectories` yourself during initialization (getting a session via `SftpRemoteFileTemplate.execute(session -> ...)`).

However, I agree that the utility should catch and ignore that exception. Please open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues).

Contributions are welcome.

Comment: [Fixed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2915).